Convert PySpark column from strings to lists
I have a PySpark column that consists of strings and lists, the datatype of this column is a string, string (nullable = true), I want to change it to be only made of lists, and convert anything that isn't a list into NULL.
I've tried this code:
df.select(F.split(F.col("major_options"),",")).alias('major_options').show()

but it will create a list out of everything instead and not change the existing list datatype, I've also tried using the cast method however I got this error:

AnalysisException: [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.CAST_WITHOUT_SUGGESTION] Cannot resolve "major_options" due to data type mismatch: cannot cast "STRING" to "ARRAY".

Edit: here is how the column looks:
|['Alloy Wheels']                                                        |
|['Light Package', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']                          |
|Steering wheel memory                                                   |
|Knee airbag                                                             |
|['Sunroof/Moonroof', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Parking Sensors']    |
|['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']                                           |


and here is how I want it to look:
|['Alloy Wheels']                                                        |
|['Light Package', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']                          |
|NULL                                                                    |
|NULL                                                                    |
|['Sunroof/Moonroof', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Parking Sensors']    |
|['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']                                           |



Could you please share some sample lists and strings from the column you are talking about so that it's easier for us to help you with this? Please read on minimal reproducible example.

You can use regexp_extract for checking if the string contains opening and closing square brackets and then split accordingly as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, when, col, lit, regexp_extract

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("['Alloy Wheels']",),
    ("['Light Package', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']",),
    ("Steering wheel memory",),
    ("Knee airbag",),
    ("['Sunroof/Moonroof', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Parking Sensors']",),
    ("['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']",),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["major_options"])

print("original schema:")
df.printSchema()

print("original df:")
df.show(truncate=False)

df = df.withColumn(
    "major_options",
    when(
        regexp_extract(col("major_options"), r"^\[(.*)\]$", 1) != "",
        split(regexp_extract(col("major_options"), r"^\[(.*)\]$", 1), ","),
    ).otherwise(lit(None)),
)

print("modified schema:")
df.printSchema()

print("modified df:")
df.show(truncate=False)

Output:
original schema:
root
 |-- major_options: string (nullable = true)

original df:
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|major_options                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|['Alloy Wheels']                                                    |
|['Light Package', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']                      |
|Steering wheel memory                                               |
|Knee airbag                                                         |
|['Sunroof/Moonroof', 'Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Parking Sensors']|
|['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth']                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

modified schema:
root
 |-- major_options: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)

modified df:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|major_options                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|['Alloy Wheels']                                                       |
|['Light Package',  'Alloy Wheels',  'Bluetooth']                       |
|NULL                                                                   |
|NULL                                                                   |
|['Sunroof/Moonroof',  'Alloy Wheels',  'Bluetooth',  'Parking Sensors']|
|['Alloy Wheels',  'Bluetooth']                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

